# How do I float questions to the top?

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions

I have several questions that have not been answered and consequently, they floated to the bottom of the question list. How do I get the question more towards the top again?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oops, I figured this out. I just edited the question and the question went back up to the top.

Comment: I don't believe the purpose of editing is to 'bump' your question. In the case that you wish to see your question answered more quickly you could offer a bounty on it.

Comment: OK..thank you for letting me know. I know that the question I asked could be answered, but it wasn't, so I wanted it to be "bumped" back up. And the editing I did was helpful editing, not just editing for the sake of editing.

Answer (score 8):

While editing does bump questions, editing for the sake of bumping a question is not encouraged. The officially sanctioned way to draw attention to a question you believe has been neglected (your own or another's) is to offer a bounty for said question so it becomes a [featured question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured).

Answer (score 2):

I recently went through my old questions (as I have a very low acceptance rate) with a view to getting them answered.

On a couple I put a bounty on, and on some others (including 1 that had had a bounty previously which hadn't resulted in an accepted answer) I edited them purely in order to bump them, but took the opportunity to completely rewrite the question in the hope that one of the reasons poor a poor answer rate was because the question was not good enough to start with.

This has worked with one of the questions, with a few more answers coming in, but not for the other.  Either way, I feel the edits were justified as they were substantially altered in an effort to increase their chances of a good answer.